# use parameter in curl command

Tags: bash, curl

I have a parameter which is container and i want to use this parameter during run curl command. I use like below but it gives an error. Any idea about that? I use it in bash script.

```
curl -X 'GET' 'https://mycontainer/api/v2.0/projects/testproject/repositories/$(container)/artifacts?page=1&page_size=1&with_tag=true&with_label=false&with_scan_overview=false&with_signature=false&with_immutable_status=false&with_accessory=false' -H 'accept: application/json' -H 'X-Accept-Vulnerabilities: application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1, application/vnd.scanner.adapter.vuln.report.harbor+json; version=1.0' -H 'authorization: Basic YWhtZXQuY2Fua2F5YUBucy5ubDo2MkVEbDIxUEM=' | jq '.[].tags[].name' > output2.txt
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it gives an error"? What have you tried to resolve that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `"` instead of `'`.
and for the variable substitution use `${}`.

The command would be:

```
curl -X 'GET' "https://mycontainer/api/v2.0/projects/testproject/repositories/${container}/artifacts?page=1&page_size=1&with_tag=true&with_label=false&with_scan_overview=false&with_signature=false&with_immutable_status=false&with_accessory=false" -H 'accept: application/json' -H 'X-Accept-Vulnerabilities: application/vnd.security.vulnerability.report; version=1.1, application/vnd.scanner.adapter.vuln.report.harbor+json; version=1.0' -H 'authorization: Basic YWhtZXQuY2Fua2F5YUBucy5ubDo2MkVEbDIxUEM=' | jq '.[].tags[].name' > output2.txt
```